# Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject -Compile Error

Tags: apex, compile-error

I am trying to instantiate

```
public WMB_AccountBillingInfoService.Unpaid[] Remittance;
```

as

```
WMB_AccountBillingInfoService.BillLocation[] billloc = custbill.BillLocation; 
    WMB_AccountBillingInfoService.Unpaid[] openRem= billloc.Remittance;
```

What will be the correct way?
Please help.

Comment: Is custbill.BillLocation a list? If so, you'd have to iterate through your BillLocation objects to get all the Unpaid objects out of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access `Remittance` from List. That's why you are getting that error.

You need to loop through the list and access `Remittance` from the SObject as follows:

```
WMB_AccountBillingInfoService.BillLocation[] billloc = custbill.BillLocation; 

for(WMB_AccountBillingInfoService.BillLocation billlocObj:billloc)
{
    WMB_AccountBillingInfoService.Unpaid[] openRem = billlocObj.Remittance;
}
```